# techniques for TDD with c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, tdd

The first thing you learn on TDD is that to make things testable, they need to be loosely coupled. And in most languages, this is accomplished by separating coupling ony through interfaces, postponing the injection of dependencies, such that mock objects can be docked to the implementations that we want to test

Now, in C++ we of course we can follow that approach to the letter using abstract classes as interfaces, but we also have the power of template programming, which resolves dependencies at compile-time

I've seen way too many examples how to do TDD with the standard approach but something between zero and zilch examples for template programming. Yes, i've seen Alexandrescu approach to using policy template parameters to defer the selection of implementations, but i'm wondering why this approach is not more widespread. Does it led to difficulties or troubling side-effects?

In short, what is the best approach to following TDD when programming with templates and compile-time polymorphism?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases I have not seen it as really any different from dependency injection through inheritance.  Just write a stub/mock class that implements the concept your template needs, instantiate the template with that class, and go from there...just like if it was an abstract interface I'd inherit from it, inject it into the object I want to test (probably during construction), and then run my tests...

Very simple example:

```
template < typename T >
T* create();

struct object {};

TEST_CASE(itCreates) {
  object * o = create<object>();
  o != 0;
  delete o;
}
```